# Winforms DataGrid Column Header Cuts off when right aligning it

Tags: winforms, datagrid

When I right align a column in a Windows Forms Datagrid, the header is right aligned as well, which is fine (mostly).  The problem is, the last part of the header text is cut off.  Is there an actual fix for this or is this a long-standing bug?

Note, this is for ye-olde DataGrid, not the DataGridView class.

```
        AmountCol.MappingName = "Amount";
        AmountCol.HeaderText = Properties.Resources.strAmount;
        AmountCol.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
```